# C++11 Template programming, delegates and lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, variadic-templates

So, it's a bit hard for me to explain this question, hope you guys will get it.

Let's say I'm trying (just for fun) to make my own Delegate class using no heap allocation and strange (read *slow*) things but just templates.

This is the scheme more or less.

```cpp
template <class T> class IDelegate;

template <class R, class ...T> class IDelegate<R(T...)>
{
    public:

        virtual R run(T...) = 0;
        inline R operator() (T... args)
        {
            return run(args...);
        }

    // ...
};

template <class T> class Delegate;

template <class R, class ...T> class Delegate<R(T...)> : public IDelegate<R(T...)>
{
    public:
        Delegate(R(*function)(T...))
            : IDelegate<R(T...)>(IDelegate<R(T...)>::FUNCTION),
              function(function)
        {}

        Delegate(std::function<R(T...)>* stdf)
            : IDelegate<R(T...)>(IDelegate<R(T...)>::FUNCTIONAL),
              stdf(stdf)
        {}

        Delegate(std::function<R(T...)>& stdf)
            : IDelegate<R(T...)>(IDelegate<R(T...)>::FUNCTIONAL),
              stdf(stdf)
        {}

        virtual ~Delegate(){}

        R run(T... args)
        {
            if(IDelegate<R(T...)>::delegate_type == IDelegate<R(T...)>::FUNCTION)
                return function(args...);
            else
                return stdf->operator()(args...);
        }

    private:

        union
        {
            R(*function)(T...);
            const std::function<R(T...)>* stdf;
        };
};

// ...

template <class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(T...)> * delegate(std::function<R(T...)>& f)
{
    return new Delegate<R(T...)>(f);
}
```

The class already works pretty well with function pointers and methods, what I'd like to achieve now is to make it work with lambdas too and do that by using `std::function` class for two reasons basically:

1. It's easier for the moment than reimplement the whole lambda thing
2. It'll make my class compatible with `std::function` for further use.

This is a working example that uses lambdas:

```cpp
auto f = new Delegate<void()>([]() { std::cout << "I'm a lambda!" << std::endl; });
f->run();

auto g = new Delegate<void(int)>([](int n) { std::cout << "Lambda: " << n << std::endl; });
g->run(5);

auto h = new Delegate<int(int)>(new std::function<int(int)>([&](int n) { return n*n; }));
std::cout << h->run(5) << std::endl;
```

Of course, the `std::function` is *almost* always implicitly called and a `std::function` object is built behind the scenes.

However, when I try to do that with the `delegate()` helper function, it doesn't work.

```cpp
auto e = delegate([]() { std::cout << "I'm a lambda!" << std::endl; });
```

`clang++` gives the following error.

```
$ clang++ delegate5.cpp --std=c++11 -O3
delegate5.cpp:263:11: error: no matching function for call to 'delegate'
        auto e = delegate([]() { std::cout << "I'm a lambda!" << std::endl; });
                 ^~~~~~~~
delegate5.cpp:120:52: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'R (*)(T...)' against '(lambda at delegate5.cpp:263:20)'
template <class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(T...)> * delegate(R(*function)(T...))
                                                   ^
delegate5.cpp:125:52: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<type-parameter-0-0 (type-parameter-0-1...)>' against '(lambda at delegate5.cpp:263:20)'
template <class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(T...)> * delegate(std::function<R(T...)>& f)
                                                   ^
delegate5.cpp:130:67: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <class O, class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(O::*)(T...)> * delegate(R(O::*method)(T...), O* parent)
                                                                  ^
delegate5.cpp:135:67: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <class O, class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(O::*)(T...)> * delegate(R(O::*method)(T...), O& parent)
                                                                  ^
delegate5.cpp:140:73: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <class O, class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(O::*)(T...) const> * delegate(R(O::*method)(T...) const, const O* parent)
                                                                        ^
delegate5.cpp:145:73: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 1 was provided
template <class O, class R, class ...T> Delegate<R(O::*)(T...) const> * delegate(R(O::*method)(T...) const, const O& parent)
                                                                        ^
1 error generated.
```

I'd like to make it work, possibly by making it all implicit, even in the last working lambda so I can achieve something like:

```cpp
auto e = delegate([]() { std::cout << "I'm lambda!" << std::endl; });
auto g = delegate([](int n) { std::cout << "Lambda: " << n << std::endl; });
auto h = delegate([&](int n) { return n*n; });
```

Sorry for the long post and thanks in advance!

Comment: It can be solved if you promise you won't use a generic lambda as an argument of `delegate()`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Could you make an example?

Comment: Here's the [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da415f1f536b1a31)

Comment: "using no heap allocation" -- um, you call `new` in `delegate`.  What exactly are you trying to do?  You do know that `new` will allocate from the free store, and hence do a heap allocation, right?  And if you build it on top of `std::function`, what benefit could it possibly give you over just using `std::function`?  Why are you forcing pointer-semantics and resource management on end-users?

Comment: Why are you `new std::function<R(T...)>`ing?  Why do you have a `std::function<R(T...)>* stdf` and `std::function<R(T...)>&` ctor with the same implementation (that *will not work*)?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki thank you very much for your example, I'll study it and let you know ;)

Comment: @Yakk dynamic allocation is in the helper, not in the class itself. Actually you can use it even without delete() helper. The other things you mentioned are just a leftover from a couple of tests (I'm still learning ;))

Comment: Note that type deduction (where you determine the type of an argument to generate the return type), and type erasure (which is what `std::function` and the above class does -- it forgets most information about a type) are *opposite* operations.  Doing type deduction in order to type erase is like building a sand castle just to smash it, or climbing a ladder just to jump to the ground on the other side.  There is rarely a good reason to do it.  Oh, and your design *nearly* requires `new`, because you are using a virtual function table

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I ran some tests and thanks to your example I managed to get it working so thank you very much!!! The drawback is that it doesn't compile on MSVC++. I used [RexTester](http://rextester.com/runcode) but it gives errors. Can you help me sort this out, please? Thank you! :)